# What word can I use in place of "facilities"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Consider this hypothetical expression,

> The event was a philanthropic one, whose aim was to raise money for the under-privileged, which will be used to provide **facilities** for them.

Facility in American literature (blogs/news pieces) refers to building where a particular activity is carried out, for example training facility etc.

In Indian English literature, it means features, such as instant messaging feature/facility, live customer support feature/facility.

In my original expression, what word can I use in place of "facility"?

Comment: you're asking for a word in Indian English, which means the same as "facilities" in AmE/BrE?

Comment: @Esther I am trying to make a point that IMO facilities is used incorrectly in Indian English. I want an alternative for facilities for AmE/BrE.

Comment: A facility can be a concrete thing, e.g. a building, but it can also be something more general, in all varieties of English, American included. Thus your example sentence does not need rewriting.

Comment: Why do you need another word? Are you looking for a word that will be understood both in Indian English and elsewhere in the English-speaking world? Please edit the question to tell us what research you've already done on your own to find a replacement word (findings from an online thesaurus, for example)

Comment: The question is closed so I cannot post an "answer" but... The best replacement word (that I can come up with) for your example sentence would be "infrastructure".  It has a slightly broader definition than "facilities" but overlaps with most/all of the implied uses in the original sentence.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible words, depending on the context. But for your example one might use:

> place

> The event was a philanthropic one, whose aim was to raise money for the under-privileged, which will be used to provide **a place** for them.

For more synyonms go [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=facilities+synonym&oq=facilities+sy&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j69i57j0i512l7.4897j1j7&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on)